# Deleting a Path Environment value in a variable with a script.bat on Windows

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, path

i created a batch-file for adding a new value in the path with

```
setx path "%PATH%;C:\Windows\System32\name" /M
```

Now i tried to delete this former added value also with a batch-file. 
i tried it with

```
reg delete "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path
```

but i couldn't find out how to select only "C:\Windows\System32\name" from all the values in Path and delete only this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove that path from the value of the variable and then re-assign it:

```
setx path "%PATH:;C:\Windows\System32\name=%" /m
```

Comment: This will expand **all** variables used in the PATH. So '%SystemRoot%\system32' will be changed to 'C:\windows\system32' in your path. This may or may not be a problem.

[setx @ learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setx)

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `pathman` from the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657):

```
USAGE:

        /as path[;path[;path ...]]
                Adds the semicolon-separated paths to the system path.

        /au path[;path[;path ...]]
                Adds the semicolon-separated paths to the user path.

        /rs path[;path[;path ...]]
                Removes the semicolon-separated paths from the system path.

        /ru path[;path[;path ...]]
                Removes the semicolon-separated paths from the user path.
```